# gradle - not able to find dependencies from maven repo

Tags: maven, dependencies, gradle

I'm having build error with following build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.foo.group:my-artifact:0.0.1-final'
}
```

group, artifact and version are correct. I've tried it with a maven project and the build was successful, but in gradle project it gives me following error:

```
:jar UP-TO-DATE
:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:test

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'.
> Could not find org.foo.group:my-artifact:0.0.1-final.
  Required by:
      :my-gradle-project:1.0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
tlin-deploy-tool
BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: This happens if the local Maven repo contains the module's POM, but not its artifact. Is this the case?

Comment: @Peter: No that's not the issue. even if you remove the artifact from local repo, it will raise the same error.

Comment: For reference, if you're facing the situation described by @PeterNiederwieser chances are that you hit [Dependency in Maven local with POM and no JAR file results in dependency resolve failure](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2709)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what went wrong, but try to check if maven and gradle are using the same .m2 repository path. It should be clearly displayed with these options:

- mvn -X
- gradle --debug

For gradle, this particular message will be shown when a jar can't be found from MavenLocal; the .m2 repository path will be shown:

> 23:44:08.152 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Resource not reachable for org.foo.group#my-artifact;0.0.1-final: res=MissingResource: /home/wisent/.m2/repository/org/foo/group/my-artifact/0.0.1-final/my-artifact-0.0.1-final.jar

Comment: thanks for this. the parent pom was missing in maven central repository.

Comment: But your maven project can build it with the same dependency. Weird.

Comment: yeah, seems maven doesn't care about parent pom.

Comment: Okay, and what if they *don't* use the same repository? How do you tell Gradle where the local maven repository is located?